# javascript href and onclick not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have a form :

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post" action="someUrl.php">
...
</form>
```

outside this form is a div containing an anchor link :

```
<a href="anotherUrl.php" onclick="document.myForm.submit();return true;">link</a>
```

i'm trying to submit myForm before proceeding to anotherUrl.php. but all it does is redirect to anotherUrl.php without submitting myForm. help?

Comment: Why is there a *link* *outside* the form to *submit* the form?  Why do you not simply use a *submit* button *inside* the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
onclick="document.forms['myForm'].submit(); return false;"
```

The return true would be redundant anyway.

You would need to redirect from someUrl.php - possibly using:

```
header("Location: http://domain.com/anotherUrl.php");
exit();
```

Comment: Probably should add `exit;` after that `header` call just to be safe.

Comment: This does not work reliably because there is a race condition caused by not canceling the click event.  You have to write `onclick="document.forms['myForm'].submit(); return false"` to do just that (the trailing semicolon is optional). The better and accessible solution is to use a submit button.

Comment: @rojoca - good point, I keep forgetting that people might not know much about that.

Comment: use location.href='anotherUrl.php' instead of header, because you can only send a header before you send any html.

Comment: @RociioLourdesRodriiguez He is not sending any HTML. You are confusing PHP generating HTTP with client-side DOM scripting.

Comment: @Duniyadnd, thanks for your input.. the form did submit, but i need to redirect using the specified anchor's href, is this possible?

Comment: @orrexian - that's where you would need to use the header() function in PHP, that would redirect it for you as long as you are not spitting out any html (including white spaces) before it. Otherwise you can do what Rociio_Lourdes_Rodriiguez suggested and use location.href to redirect.

Comment: IMHO, `die(…);` should only be used for errors; write `exit;` here instead.

Comment: @PointedEars - not sure I agree, as I believe it is more of a personal preference - but to keep you happy, changed. :)

Answer (score -1):

Are you using any javascript framework? It would be easier for you to achieve by using jquery or by creating a function that will trigger the submission of form then the redirection.

Comment: −1. It would be easier to use a submit button.

Comment: Well, i guess you're right. But the fact that he's using an achor tag in submitting the form I thought it might be better to use it. Nevertheless, thanks for pointing that out. @PointedEars